# ALSA: buffer underrun on snd_pcm_writei call

Tags: linux, alsa

I'm getting buffer underruns when running an old program I recently brought back from the ashes.

The program loads up a raw sound file fully into memory (2100 bytes  long, 525 frames) and prepares ALSA for output (44.1khz, 2 channels, signed 16 bit):

```
if ((err = snd_pcm_set_params(audio_handle,
                              SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE,
                              SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED,
                              2,
                              44100,
                              1,
                              sound.playback_us)) < 0) {
  printf("E: Failed to prepare PCM: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
  return -1;
}
```

PCM state is `PREPARED` prior to first playing the sound. Sound plays correctly the first time around, however, the second time it is played, state is `RUNNING` and a `-EPIPE` ("Broken pipe") is thrown by `snd_pcm_writei`. Playback logic:

```
frames = snd_pcm_writei(audio_handle,
                        sound.data,
                        write_size);

if(frames < 0) {
  printf("E: %s: attempting to recover\n", snd_strerror(frames));
  frames = snd_pcm_recover(audio_handle, frames, 0);

  if(frames < 0) {
    printf("E: snd_pcm_writei failed\n");
    break;
  }
} else if(frames > 0 && frames < write_size)
  printf("E: Short write (expected %li, wrote %li)\n", write_size, frames);
else
  printf("wrote %li frames\n", frames);
```

Strangely, it plays correctly at the third time, failing once again the following time. In other words, it fails with a `-EPIPE` error every other time.

For the sake of simplicity, I'm playing the sounds at 1 second intervals.

What's wrong with the logic above?

---

Updated code to use new ALSA API; can be found at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7257181/

---

**EDIT**

Just found out that if one actually tests for an `-EPIPE` condition and re-prepares the PCM handle before re-issuing the `snd_pcm_writei` call, all is good.  My (new) question then is... why?

```
if(frames == -EPIPE) {
  snd_pcm_prepare(pcm.handle);
  frames = snd_pcm_writei(pcm.handle,
                          sound.data, //sound.data + (offset << 1),
                          write_size);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you fill the buffer with 525 frames (about 12 ms) and then wait for one second, you are guaranteed to get an underrun because there is no data for the remaining 988 ms.

You could use `snd_pcm_drain` to wait until the actual data has stopped playing (note: typcially, the device will not actually stop until the next period boundary).
Alternatively, continue feeding zero samples into the buffer.

Comment: Jeez, I've clearly misunderstood how playback with ALSA actually works. From your comment I gather that right after playing the sound, which is only a few milliseconds in length, I have to drain and close the connection instead of keeping it open (as I do at the moment) and reopen whenever necessary?

Comment: You don't need close/reopen; `snd_pcm_prepare` suffices.