# ALSA API using in Matlab - buffer issue

Tags: c, linux, matlab, audio, alsa

being part of a lab course, I have to update the simulation about Pulse Coded Modulation. Initially, the simulation was written in 1998 using the OSS (open sound system) and was never updated thereafter. I have rewritten the entire code and ported it to ALSA.

The code itself is a bit long, that's why I haven't put it here but am providing a link.

Now to my issue: Whenever I want to play a vector of random length containing many samples, I start hearing weird periodic random noises. I have a feeling it's due to a buffer underrun. For a better understanding, I have recorded the output.

I believe it has to do something with the parameters I've set. Even though I tried out many cases, I didn't come to a solution.

Just take a look at the period size, buffer size, periods and the sbplay(..) function. PS.: My HW is set such that buffer size = period size * periods

I hope you can help me somehow! Thanks in advance

[Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1d610wce8nvrwy/realtest.c?dl=0)

[Output WAV](https://www.dropbox.com/s/im3q8rdjr2tdxx0/Record_0001.wav?dl=0)

BTW.: [ALSA: buffer underrun on snd_pcm_writei call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092895/alsa-buffer-underrun-on-snd-pcm-writei-call)
didn't help me much...

Answer (score 0):

Efe,

Why don't you try the audioplayer/audiorecorder functions in MATLAB. They use ALSO on Linux. If you want greater control over the latency try the dsp.AudioPlayer/AudioRecorder system objects.

Dinesh

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dinesh! 
I will try it out later on. Hopefully my advisor is fine with that solution :))